# PHP update sql record

Tags: php, html, sql

Somehow I get my sql error while trying to update a record in my sql db

Here's my current code

html form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="end.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Kommentar"><p>
<input type="submit" value="Stop arbejde">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

end.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="password";
$db_name="db";
$tbl_name="log";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$datetime=date("y/m/d H:i:s");
$editit=date("W/D");

$sql="UPDATE log SET end=$datetime, comment=$comment WHERE editid='$editit'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "Successful<BR>";
}
else {
echo "Fejl";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

What am I doing wrong since I get that error "Fejl" ?

Comment: I think in PHP you have to add {} or use "+$var+"around variable names in a string? take a look at your $sql string again

Comment: @GeneParmesan: Incorrect

Comment: @OptimusCrime I knew that something had to be done with the sql string and variables. Apparently, they just need single quotes.

Comment: @GeneParmesan: That is correct, but in PHP you can have variables within double quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

string must be wrap with single quotes

```
$sql="UPDATE log SET end='$datetime', comment='$comment' WHERE editid='$editit'";
```

but your query is prone to `SQL Injection`. please take time to read the article below

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The variable names in $sql should be inside single inverted comas.

```
$sql="UPDATE log SET end='$datetime', comment='$comment' WHERE editid='$editit'";
```

And also, you should remove paragraph tag from html code in form tag.